# Ajax AutoCompleteExtender does not work in production

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a VS2010 ASP.Net web app that uses the ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender. When I am developing the application and run the app from VS2010, everything works. But when I publish the app to QA or production or even a local site on my PC, the ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender does not do anything. I get no errors, just nothing happens. My service method does not get called.

Below is my AutoCompleteExtender control. When a user starts typing into the textbox, the "PerformSearch" service method is suppose to be called and a drop down appears. However, when I begin typing, nothing happens. My text is entered into the textbox but the service method is never called. I can call the service method by click a button, but the AutoCompleteExtender does not call the service method, but this only fails in production or QA.

Am I missing a file when Publishing that needs deployed?

```
 <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
           runat="server" 
            BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"
            ID="autoComplete1" 
            TargetControlID="cboPartno"
            ServicePath="..\AutoComplete.asmx" 
            ServiceMethod="PerformSearch"
            MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
            CompletionInterval="1000"
            EnableCaching="true"
            CompletionSetCount="20"
            CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" 
            CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" 
            CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
            DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
            ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true" >
                  <Animations>
                <OnShow>
                    <Sequence>
                        <%-- Make the completion list transparent and then show it --%>
                        <OpacityAction Opacity="0" />
                        <HideAction Visible="true" />

                        <%--Cache the original size of the completion list the first time
                            the animation is played and then set it to zero --%>
                        <ScriptAction Script="
                            // Cache the size and setup the initial size
                            var behavior = $find('AutoCompleteEx');
                            if (!behavior._height) {
                                var target = behavior.get_completionList();
                                behavior._height = target.offsetHeight - 2;
                                target.style.height = '0px';
                            }" />

                        <%-- Expand from 0px to the appropriate size while fading in --%>
                        <Parallel Duration=".4">
                            <FadeIn />
                            <Length PropertyKey="height" StartValue="0" EndValueScript="$find('AutoCompleteEx')._height" />
                        </Parallel>
                    </Sequence>
                </OnShow>
                <OnHide>
                    <%-- Collapse down to 0px and fade out --%>
                    <Parallel Duration=".4">
                        <FadeOut />
                        <Length PropertyKey="height" StartValueScript="$find('AutoCompleteEx')._height" EndValue="0" />
                    </Parallel>
                </OnHide>
            </Animations>
            </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```